# Spring Data MongoDB Index not created when no data available

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spock

I am using Spring Data Framework for MongoDB with Groovy and can't solve my problem: 
What I want: I want Spring Data to create my MongoDB collection with 2 indices. I have my POJO Class

```
@Document(collection='language')
class language {
    @Id
    String Id

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    String isoCode

    String description
}
```

That is my repository:

```
public interface LanguageRepository extends MongoRepository<Language, String>

  List<Language> findByisoCode(String isoCode);
}
```

Maybe there are some more annotations, I am writing the code without having my sourcecode right here...

I have written a spock test that checks if it is possible to insert two languages with the same isoCode and expects an exceptoion. The Spock test wires up the application context and works pretty fine except of one point: The index is not created when I run the test the first time.

I wire up my test, the test inserts twi languages with the same isoCode to my MongoDB and the test fails because there is no index that prevents duplicate isoCodes. I can see this in the MongoShell as well. The test fails because there is no index violation and no exception.
Now when I run the same test again my application can't even start because Spring Data seems to create the index on my MongoDB - but this also fails, because there are duplicate entries in the database already and creation of the index fails (of course...). When I delete one of the entries manually via MongoShell and run the same test again everything works fine, because the index can be created and I get my expected exception.

Can anybody tell me if and why mongoDB can only create indices if there are already entries in the collection? And if it is that way: how do I handle this issue best?

Kind regards
Sebastian

edit Spock Test:

```
def 'There must not be duplicate languages'() {
        setup:
        Language lang1 = new Language(
                isoCode: 'de-DE',
                description: 'Deutsch (Deutschland)'
        )
        Language lang2 = new Language(
                isoCode: 'de-DE',
                description: 'Deutsch (Schweiz)'
        )
        languageRepository.save(lang1)

        when:
        languageRepository.save(lang2)

        then:
        final org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException ex = thrown()

        cleanup:
        languageRepository.deleteAll()

    }
```

Comment: Show the code of the Spock test.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is not really Spock. You say "The index is not created when I run the test the first time". So if you create a normal main() method (and not a Spock test) that saves a language, is the index created or not? If not then it is a bug in Mongo and/or Spring data.